# When I turn on the computer ( or restart ) the screen turns on and off three times before booting grub. How to stop this behaviour?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

**OS**: Arch Linux x86_64
**Host**: 81Y3 IdeaPad L3 15IML05
**Kernel**: 6.8.1-arch1-1

```
~ λ  lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     2G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    12G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   100G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 362.9G  0 part /home
```

I have updated the UEFI to the latest version `"EJCN31WW"`

Information about the EFI partition:

```
File System: fat32
Flags: boot, esp
```

Grub configuration file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true
```

I have tried missing with the UEFI settings, but with no success.
I have noticed that if i entered the boot menu and selected grub the first time it turns on, it will boot grub right away.

So, what I think that it could be caused by (I'm probably wrong XD):

1. The EFI partition is too large (2Gb).
2. The EFI partition doesn't have the right format.
3. It tries to boot grub, but it fails.

I can't think of a solution. Plz share your thoughts.
And Thanks.

Edit:

this is the boot partition tree

```
/boot
├── EFI
│   └── GRUB
│       └── grubx64.efi
├── grub
```